# Calculating dates in loops

Tags: php, date, datetime

Requirement is as follows:
We deliver the products only on Monday, Wednesday and Friday.
If the order is placed before 5 pm then the order will be delivered on the same day (if it is MWF) else the order will be delivered on the next delivery date.
The order will be delivered in 3 parts. 1st and 2nd products on 1st delivery , 3rd and 4th product on the 2nd delivery and 5th and 6th on 3rd delivery.
Need to print the delivery dates with the products to be delivered on that day using PHP

```
    <?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
//Starting date
$date=date('m/d/Y h:i:s a',time());
//echo $date;
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
{
    echo "Entered in the loop \n";
    $date=calculateDeliveryDate($date);
    if($i==1)
    {
        echo "First delivery date ".$date."\n";
    }
    else
    {
        if($i==2)
        {
            echo "Second delivery date ".$date."\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Third delivery date ".$date."\n";
        }
    }
    $date=date_add(strtotime($date),date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 days"));
}
function calculateDeliveryDate($dt)
{
    echo "Entered the function \n";
    $dayOfTheWeek=date('D',strtotime($dt));
    $timeOfTheWeek=date('H',strtotime($dt));
    //echo $dayOfTheWeek."\n";
    if(($dayOfTheWeek=='Mon' || $dayOfTheWeek=='Wed' || $dayOfTheWeek=='Fri') && $timeOfTheWeek<17)
    {
        return $dt;
    }
    else
    {
        if($dayOfTheWeek=='Mon' || $dayOfTheWeek=='Wed' || $dayOfTheWeek=='Sat')
        {
            $dt=date_add(strtotime($date),date_interval_create_from_date_string("2 days"));
            return $dt;
        }
        else
        {
            if($dayOfTheWeek=='Fri')
            {
                $dt=date_add(strtotime($date),date_interval_create_from_date_string("3 days"));
                return $dt;
            }
            else
            {
                $dt=date_add(strtotime($date),date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 days"));
                return $dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Suggestions are as follows: We need to see your code What you've done. Or What are the problems you're facing?

Comment: please feed us with some code you tried so we can be of much help...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a community which helps if you have problem.
But not a place which you can get done your assignments .
In-order to help you have to show people what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? Good luck.

```css
.productLayout {
  background: #CCC;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sameDayDelivery {
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.nextDayDelivery {
  width: 200px;
  background: crimson;
}
```

```html
<?php
 
 $orderArray = array(
      array("name" => "product1", "orderDate" => "2017-10-28 09:00:00"), 
      array("name" => "product2", "orderDate" => "2017-10-29 12:30:00"),
      array("name" => "product3", "orderDate" => "2017-10-31 13:26:00"),
      array("name" => "product4", "orderDate" => "2017-11-1 16:49:00"),
      array("name" => "product5", "orderDate" => "2017-11-2 17:00:00"),
            array("name" => "product6", "orderDate" => "2017-11-3 16:59:00")
      );
      
  // LOOP THROUGH DATES
 for($i = 0; $i < count($orderArray); $i++){
        
        $orderDate = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $orderArray[$i]["orderDate"]);
        
        if(CheckTime($orderDate) == true && CheckDay($orderDate)) {
            PrintLayout($orderArray[$i]["name"], $orderDate, $orderDate, true);
  } else {
            PrintLayout($orderArray[$i]["name"], $orderDate, NextDeliverDate($orderDate), false);
  }
        
 }
    
    // return true if time is before 5:00PM
    function CheckTime($time){
        $d = new DateTime(date_format($time, "Y-m-d")); // returns the time
        $deadline = date_time_set($d, 16, 59, 59); // returns day of week in text
       
        if($time <= $deadline){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    // return true if Monday, Wednesday, Friday
    function CheckDay($time){
        
        $day = date_format($time, 'w');
        
        if($day == 1 || $day == 3 || $day == 5){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
         }
    }
    
    // return day of the week that the order will be delivered
    function NextDeliverDate($time){
        
        $date = date_format($time, 'w');
        
        $deliveryTime = date_format($time, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
        
        if($date != 6){
            $d = new DateTime($deliveryTime);
            $d -> modify("+1 day");
            return $d;
        } else {
            $d = new DateTime($deliveryTime);
            $d -> modify("+2 day");
            return $d;
        }
       
    }
    
    // Just a simple layout function to print everything easily.
    function PrintLayout($productName, $orderDate, $deliveryDate, $sameDay){
        
        if($sameDay == true){
            $attentionText = "Same Day";
            $attentionClass = "sameDayDelivery";
        } else {
            $attentionText = "Next Delivery Day";
            $attentionClass = "nextDayDelivery";
        }
        
        
        $orderDay = date_format($orderDate, "Y-m-d"); // returns the time
        $orderDayText = date_format($orderDate, "l"); // returns day of week in text
        $orderTime = date_format($orderDate, "H:i:s"); // returns the time
        
        $deliveryDay = date_format($deliveryDate, "Y-m-d"); // returns the time
        $deliveryDayText = date_format($deliveryDate, "l"); // returns day of week in text
        $deliveryTime = date_format($deliveryDate, "H:i:s"); // returns the time
                
        echo "<div class='productLayout'>
              <h2>Product Name: ".$productName."</h2>
              <div class='".$attentionClass."'>".$attentionText."</div>";
        
        echo "Order Date: [".$orderDay."][".$orderTime."][".$orderDayText."]<br>";
        
        echo "Deliver Date: [".$deliveryDay."][".$deliveryTime."][".$deliveryDayText."]";
        
        echo "</div>";
    }
    

    
    
    
 echo "<br><hr><br>
 The order will be delivered in 3 parts. <br>
 1st and 2nd products on 1st delivery<br>
 3rd and 4th product on the 2nd delivery<br>
 5th and 6th on 3rd delivery.<br>
<br>
 Need to print the delivery dates with the products to be delivered on that day using PHP
 ";
 
?>
```